# Recuperar informações sobre quais Tabelas/Procedimentos/Visões são mais acessadas no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    db_name(database_id) as banco, 
    object_name(object_id) as objeto, 
    stats.user_seeks,
    stats.user_scans,
    stats.user_lookups,
    stats.user_updates
from 
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats as stats
```

Eu tenho esse SELECT que me traz informações agrupadas pelo banco, achei que o objeto se referia a uma tabela, visão, stored procedure ou trigger, mas não obtive o resultado que queria.

Existe um SELECT que me traga essas informações?

Resultado esperado:

```
database objeto  select data_ultimo_select update data_ultimo_update delete data_ultimo_delete
-------- ------- ------ ------------------ ------ ------------------ ------ ------------------
banco1   tabela1 1500   01-01-2013         500    01-01-2014         500    01-01-2015
banco2   tabela2 2500   01-01-2011         1500   01-01-2012         1500   01-01-2013
```

Será que é possível?

Já pesquisei em vários lugares e não encontrei onde o SQL SERVER guarda, se é que guarda, essas informações.

Comment: Qual o problema com o resultado obtido?

Comment: vou editar a pergunta com o resultado que gostaria de obter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a seguinte função:

```
CREATE FUNCTIOn fn_TablesLastUpdateDate(@Date NVARCHAR(20))

RETURNS @table TABLE(TableName NVARCHAR(40), LastUpdated Datetime)

AS

BEGIN

    IF(@Date='') OR (@Date Is Null) OR (@Date='0')

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @table
            SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT TABLENAME, LASTUPDATED FROM 
            (
                SELECT  B.NAME AS 'TABLENAME', MAX(STATS_DATE (ID,INDID)) AS LASTUPDATED
                FROM    SYS.SYSINDEXES AS A
                        INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS AS B ON A.ID = B.OBJECT_ID
                WHERE   B.TYPE = 'U'  AND STATS_DATE (ID,INDID) IS NOT NULL 
                GROUP BY B.NAME
            ) AS A
            ORDER BY LASTUPDATED DESC
        END
    ELSE

        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @table
            SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT TABLENAME,LASTUPDATED FROM 
            (
                SELECT  B.NAME AS 'TABLENAME', MAX(STATS_DATE (ID,INDID)) AS LASTUPDATED,
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(STATS_DATE (ID,INDID)), 103) as Date
                FROM    SYS.SYSINDEXES AS A
                        INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS AS B ON A.ID = B.OBJECT_ID
                WHERE   B.TYPE = 'U'  AND STATS_DATE (ID,INDID) IS NOT NULL 
                GROUP BY B.NAME
            ) AS A
            WHERE Date=@Date
            ORDER BY LASTUPDATED DESC
        END
    RETURN

END
```

Uso:

```
SELECT * from fn_TablesLastUpdateDate('14/01/2015')
```

[Esta é a resposta aceita desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227707/how-to-get-last-insert-update-delete-datetime-on-sql-server-2005).

Comment: Pelo que entendi, sua função retorna apenas a última data em que a tabela foi atualizada, eu gostaria de obter dados mais precisos sobre a quantidade de vezes que tal tabela foi consultada, atualizada, etc. Como exemplo eu poderia criar um trigger para gerar um log em cima de cada tabela pegando as operações de insert, update e delete, mas mesmo assim ficaria sem a informação de quantas vezes a tabela foi consultada, isso sem contar que o meu banco ficaria cheio de trigger, o que não acho viável.

Comment: Não sei se tem estatística pra tudo isso. O que você pode fazer é registrar o timestamp de cada operação em outra tabela usando triggers, mas isso com certeza vai impactar no desempenho.

Comment: oh loco meu, nem terminei o comentário e você já respondeu também, tá rápido hein.

Comment: A minha dúvida quando fiz a pergunta era justamente essa, saber se o SQL SERVER tem algum controle interno sobre essas informações.

Comment: @dil_oliveira O site fica aberto aqui pra mim diretão. Mas respondendo, nativamente o máximo que é possível é o que está na resposta. Mais do que isso, você precisaria criar seus próprios controles.

Comment: Estranho, o @seunome não saiu porque?

Comment: Tem que digitar tudo junto, @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Valeu mesmo, vou ver o que consigo fazer com as informações disponíveis.